# When I full-screen a flash video, it takes over both monitors

Tags: video, graphics, multiple-monitors, flash

If I play a Hulu video in a browser on one monitor and then click the "full-screen" button, the video takes over the whole screen. But a glitchy copy of the video also takes over my second screen. But I'm not running my two monitors in mirror mode. I'm using a Radeon HD 4650 graphics chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash didn't know this, just until recently, so try updating flash and download the latest one. The latest features include fullscreen only on one display.

Check [this](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/12/new-flash-player-10-2-goes-easy-on-the-cpu/) article.